# Magento2.3.2: Why deleted urls coming again and again

Tags: 404-page, magento2.3.2

My website is [Depoto](https://www.depoto.com/)

I have some categories, products, Static blocks and cms pages.

I deleted some of the pages and etc.

I was using Magecomp's 404 notifier extension. There I am getting 100's of deleted URLs too.

I checked in url_rewrite table too. But i did not find any deleted urls entry from this table.

For example, https://www.depoto.com/depoto-mining  is not in my website. I deleted so far back. But why its showing in notificatiions?

Answer (score 0):

It will be cache , You may need to clear your cache and static contents .

clear your "var" folder and run the below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I did already. But the urls are coming continuoesly. The answer came from extension support is the entries are in database, You need to remove from the db.